# Variably modified array at file scope

Tags: arrays, objective-c, static, constants

I want to create a constant static array to be used throughout my Objective-C implementation file, similar to something like this at the top level of my ".m" file:

```
static const int NUM_TYPES = 4;
static int types[NUM_TYPES] = {
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4 };
```

I plan on using `NUM_TYPES` later on in the file, so I wanted to put it in a variable.

However, when I do this, I get the error

> "Variably modified 'types' at file scope"

I gather that this may have something to do with the array size being a variable (I don't get this message when I put an integer literal there, like `static int types[4]`).

I want to fix this, but maybe I am going about it all wrong...I have two goals here:

1. To have an array which is accessible throughout the file
2. To encapsulate `NUM_TYPES` into a variable, so I don't have the same literal scattered about different places in my file

What can I do?

I found this in the C FAQ (11.8): *[I don't understand why I can't use const values in initializers and array dimensions](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constasconst.html)*

Comment: What happens if you do it as a define instead? `#define kNUM_TYPES 4` ?

Comment: That works...for some reason I was trying to stay away from using the preprocessor because I thought I remembered reading that somewhere, but I just did some more research and couldn't find a good reason not to use it in this case.  I think it may be less desirable if I'm creating objects in the preprocessor (like `@"An NSString literal"`)

The only thing wrong with your piece of code is that there's no need for the semicolon.

Comment: The corresponding canonical question for [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29): *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/)*

Answer (score 67):

The reason for this warning is that ['const' in C doesn't mean constant. It means "read-only"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323204809/http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c/explanation-needed-for-const-int-error-variably-m/284354). So the value is stored at a memory address and could potentially be changed by machine code.

Comment: Modifying an object defined `const` (such as by casting away `const` from a pointer and storing a value) is undefined behaviour; therefore, the value of such an object is a compile-time or run-time constant (depending on storage duration). The value cannot be used in a constant expression simply because the C standard does not say it can be. (Casting away `const` and storing a value is permitted if the destination object is defined without `const` or dynamically allocated; string literals are not `const` but may not be written to.)

Comment: @jilles "could potentially be changed by machine code" does not mean that the author of this answer meant "could potentially changed by C code". Furthermore, this does have another very good reason: there can be `extern` constants in different TUs of which the value is not known when compiling the current TU.

Comment: A way to improve this answer would be to show how to resolve this issue.

Comment: An attempt to resolve this issue is [CygnusX1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712592/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope/40961072#40961072).

Comment: But this question is for Objective-C, not C: *"...throughout my Objective-C implementation file"*

Answer (score 35):

If you're going to use the preprocessor anyway, as per the other answers, then you can make the compiler determine the value of `NUM_TYPES` automagically:

```
#define NUM_TYPES (sizeof types / sizeof types[0])
static int types[] = { 
  1,
  2, 
  3, 
  4 };
```

Comment: Wow that's really cool...I did not know that was possible.  I assume the cost of this computation is negligible.  Might I also assume that a compiler could optimize this to a static value?

Comment: Yes, the result of `sizeof` on objects like that is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 22):

```
#define NUM_TYPES 4
```

Answer (score 11):

It is also possible to use enumeration.

```
typedef enum {
    typeNo1 = 1,
    typeNo2,
    typeNo3,
    typeNo4,
    NumOfTypes = typeNo4
}  TypeOfSomething;
```

Answer (score 10):

As it is already explained in other answers, `const` in C merely means that a variable is read-only. It is still a run-time value. However, you can use an `enum` as a real constant in C:

```
enum { NUM_TYPES = 4 };
static int types[NUM_TYPES] = { 
  1, 2, 3, 4
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is the real answer to the *implied* question for many coming from [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) (or C++-like, e.g. [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino)).

Comment: Though this question is for Objective-C, not C: *"...throughout my Objective-C implementation file"*

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, this is a flaw in many C compilers. I know for a fact that the compilers I worked with do not store a "static const" variable at an address, but replace the use in the code by the very constant. This can be verified as you will get the same checksum for the produced code when you use a preprocessors #define directive and when you use a static const variable.

Either way, you should use static const variables instead of #defines whenever possible as the static const is type-safe.

Comment: That sounds pretty bad, since you can take the address of a `static const` variable. The behavior you're describing might be a valid optimization, but it's certainly not something that could always work.

Comment: It is actually fine.  It is OK for the C compiler to replace individual uses of const global variables with the constant value wherever possible.  If all references to a variable are converted to constants, then the compiler can remove it entirely.  If you use the address anywhere, it won't be removed.  None of that changes that according to the language standard, C does not allow global arrays with an variable as the size, whether the variable is const or not.

Comment: How is any of this relevant to a question about Objective-C, which is a different language to C?