# Why doesn't gcc allow a const int as a case expression?

Tags: c, objective-c, compiler-construction, constants

I was looking at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712592/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope) and got to thinking about const ints versus #defines and realized I don't actually understand why the compiler can't deal with this. Could someone shed some light as to why the following code

```
const int FOO = 10;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    switch(argc)
    {
        case FOO: { printf("foo\n"); }
        default:  { printf("default\n"); }
    }
}
```

results in

```
error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
```

I read the ISO-C99 spec which states in 6.8.4.2.3 that

> The expression of each case label
>   shall be an integer constant
>   expression and no two of the case
>   constant expressions in the same
>   switch statement shall have the same
>   value after conversion.

I understand why the case expression must be constant, but not why only a literal makes the compiler (gcc 4.2.1) happy.

Comment: Interestingly that code appears to compile and run just fine on gcc-4.3.4: http://ideone.com/n1bmIb
Edit: Ah.. but only as C++, not C.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A constant expression is not the same as a const-qualified type value, even though technically the value is known by the compiler at the point of the `case` statement.

Imagine what would happen if another file declared `extern const int FOO` and tried to use it the same way. The compiler wouldn't know what `FOO` was because it was defined in another file. Even though it has a constant *value*, it is not a constant *expression*.

Comment: `extern` example doesn't make anyting clear and doesn't really explain anything. In C++ language you can also declate an `extern` constant, just like in C, yet in C++ it is perfectly legal to use `const int` objects in constant expressions, including case labels (not `extern` ones, of course). The only true answer to the original question is that it was done that way historically. From the very beginning in C the term "constant" meant literal numerical values, not `const` objects. Why? Just because.

Comment: Well, the extern example was the one I couldn't come up with that the compiler couldn't deal with. Your comment is valuable, though. Thanks.

Comment: So, is there no way to avoid using magic numbers in case statements?

Comment: @Harkonian: You could use preprocessor macros, i.e. `#define FOO 10`.

Comment: I'd say the second part of the spec description is more important here. Even if compiler *could* somehow construct the necessary switch code to reuse const values determined at linking time, there'll be no guarantee that they will have actually different values. Even if you can do all that, the actual `switch` code will be supposedly more complex than a set of `if`s, so there's no actual benefit supporting it. Just my thoughts.

Comment: The extern issue is a nice explanation thanks. But two questions: why doesn't C at least allow this for local `static const int`? And how does C++ cope with this?