# Why does Clang accept `static const` as case label but GCC does not?

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement, clang

With Clang, this code compiles fine, with no errors nor warnings:

```c
static const int ZERO = 0;

int main() {
    switch (0) {
        case ZERO: break;
    }
}
```

But with GCC, I get an error:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:5:9: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
    5 |         case ZERO: break;
      |         ^~~~
```

Why is that?

---

Note: In this case I can just use a `#define`, but I'm wondering why there's a difference between Clang and GCC's behavior here.

I'm using Apple Clang 11.0.3 (seems to be installed via Xcode) and GCC 10.2.0, but I was able to reproduce this problem on Godbolt with Clang trunk and GCC trunk. Both locally and in Godbolt I was using x86-64.

Comment: It’s the difference between a constant integer and an integer constant.  Clang is not following the C standard when it accepts the code.  What compilation options are you using with each compiler?

Comment: I'm using the same options for both: `cc -xc -` (my `cc` is Clang) and `gcc-10 -xc -`.

Comment: AFAIK, GCC 10 effectively uses `-std=gnu11` to compile when you don't specify otherwise.  (I don't think it uses C18, not that it would make much difference.)  I note that you've not identified which version of Clang you're using.  It may be following a different standard.  It may be using different GCC-compatibility assumptions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have edited my question to include version information.

Comment: There must be a diagnostic if you invoke the compiler in conforming mode (otherwise it is a compiler bug), e.g. use `-std=c11 -pedantic` (or whatever standard revision)

Answer (score 0):

This was in the sidebar:

[switch case: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069737/switch-case-error-case-label-does-not-reduce-to-an-integer-constant?rq=1)

Apparently 'const' in this case is not a constant expression, but a constant variable... well, just read the post. Seems like `clang` has different rules. Another reason why it is always good to compile on more than one compiler.

Comment: I also saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712711/why-doesnt-gcc-allow-a-const-int-as-a-case-expression in the sidebar, but I would like to hear more about *why* there is a difference in behavior — it seems weird that GCC refuses to compile at all, while Clang doesn't even give a warning.

Comment: @Camelid Turning up the warnings (or errors with `-Werror`) in Clang also causes it not to be accepted, saying that it's a GNU extension.

Comment: @Camelid Good point. Now I'd like to know why the difference too.

Comment: @ThomasJager I am not able to reproduce what you are describing. What flags are you passing and to which version of Clang?