# What is the standard to declare constant variables in ANSI C?

Tags: c

I am teaching myself C by going over my C++ book and recoding the problems in C. I wanted to know the correct industry standard way of declaring variables constant in C. Do you still use the *#define* directive outside of main, or can you use the C++ style *const int* inside of main?

Comment: "constant variable" is an oxymoron :)

Comment: It may be an oxymoron, but that's exactly what the `const` keyword creates in C - not a *constant*, but rather a non-modifiable variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944041/advantage-and-disadvantages-of-defines-vs-constants

Comment: The correct term for C is `const`-qualified object, that is this is not a property of the variable but of the object it refers to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` in C is very different to `const` in C++.

In C it means that the object won't be modified through that identifier:

```
int a = 42;
const int *b = &a;

*b = 12; /* invalid, the contents of `b` are const */
a = 12; /* ok, even though *b changed */
```

Also, unlike C++, const objects cannot be used, for instance, in switch labels:

```
const int k = 0;
switch (x) {
    case k: break; /* invalid use of const object */
}
```

So ... it really depends on what you need.

Your options are

- `#define`: really const but uses the preprocessor
- `const`: not really const
- `enum`: limited to `int`

larger example

```
#define CONST 42
const int konst = 42;
enum /*unnamed*/ { fixed = 42 };

printf("%d %d %d\n", CONST, konst, fixed);

/* &CONST makes no sense */
&konst; /* can be used */
/* &fixed makes no sense */
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern C supports both `#define`s and `const` globals. However, `#define`s are usually preferred for true constants; this is because `#define`s can be inlined into the place where they are used, while `const` globals generally require a memory read, particularly if they're defined in a different translation unit.

That said, complex constant structures are a good use for `const` globals - strings, `struct`s, arrays, etc.

Comment: I don't at all agree that `#define`s are usually preferred to true constants. `enum` avoids the problems you mentioned and provides a symbolic name. Or rather: I don't agree that they usually *should* be preferred to true constants.

Comment: enums are limited to the range of an `int`, note. This is important when working on embedded platforms...

Comment: On modern systems `const`s are placed in the  .rodata section which actually protects them

Answer (score 0):

In most modern implementations the compiler is trying to do more just to bare the access via the symbol by placing the global `const` variables in the read only sections. It actually protects them on many systems  against change.
Some examples : segfault on Linux systems and errors on Windows or placing the code in the FLASH when using the micro controllers.

It is of course 100% implementation, but it is good to know that modern machines with memory protection hardware and modern compilers  do more than only follow the standard

Answer (score 0):

Variables qualified by `const` are not considered **compile-time constant**, they have one significant limitation: `const int` cannot be used to define the size of an array.(historical reasons but not a limitation of the compiler, C++ corrects this oversight though)

You can choose:

```
#define SIZE 5   /* preprocessor */
enum { SIZE=5 }; /* compiler */
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard that is followed in most C programs is to have all constants as macros (#define) in a separate header file.