# Error if i declare constant with #define or const in my C program

Tags: c, gcc

I use gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1).
I wrote a simple program in C to implement and test a integer stack. Stack is implemented by the STACK structure. I used a constant named STACKSIZE to define the STACK's size.
My program code looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define STACKSIZE 10;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int items[STACKSIZE];
} STACK;

void push(STACK *ps, int x)
{
    if (ps->size == STACKSIZE) {
        fputs("Error: stack overflow\n", stderr);
        abort();
    } else
        ps->items[ps->size++] = x;
}

int pop(STACK *ps)
{
    if (ps->size == 0){
        fputs("Error: stack underflow\n", stderr);
        abort();
    } else
    return ps->items[--ps->size];
}

int main() {
    STACK st;
    st.size = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < STACKSIZE + 1; i++) {
        push(&st, i);
    }
    while(st.size != 0)
        printf("%d\n", pop(&st));
    printf("%d\n", pop(&st));
    return 0;
}
```

when i used 
    `#define STACKSIZE 10;`
gcc would return following errors:

```
ex_stack1.c:8: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
ex_stack1.c:9: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
ex_stack1.c: In function ‘push’:
ex_stack1.c:13: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
ex_stack1.c:17: error: ‘STACK’ has no member named ‘items’
ex_stack1.c: In function ‘pop’:
ex_stack1.c:26: error: ‘STACK’ has no member named ‘items’
ex_stack1.c: In function ‘main’:
ex_stack1.c:33: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
```

when i used

```
const int STACKSIZE=10;
```

gcc would return following error:

```
ex_stack1.c:8: error: variably modified ‘items’ at file scope
```

when i used

```
enum {STACKSIZE=10};
```

gcc would compile my program successfully.

What happenned? How should i modify my program to use

```
#define STACKSIZE 10;
```

or

```
const int STACKSIZE=10;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the semicolon, it's wrong

```
#define STACKSIZE 10;
                    ^
```

If you keep it the preprocessor will translate `int items[STACKSIZE];` into the obviously wrong `int items[10;];`.

For the `const` bit, there is a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constasconst.html).

> The value of a const-qualified object **is not a constant expression in
>   the full sense of the term**, and cannot be used for array dimensions,
>   case labels, and the like.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can view the results of the preprocessor by making use of the -E option to gcc.  That is,

```
gcc -E ex_stack1.c -o ex_stack1.i
```

Examination of the resulting ex_stack1.i file would have made the problem more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` does textual replacement.  Since you have:

```
#define STACKSIZE 10;
```

then

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int items[STACKSIZE];
} STACK;
```

becomes:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int items[10;];
} STACK;
```

In C, `const` is used to declare *variables* that can't (easily) be modified.  They are not *compile-time* constants.

`enum`, however, does define a compile-time constant.  In general, you should prefer `enum` over `const int` over `#define` where possible. (See [Advantage and disadvantages of #define vs. constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944041/advantage-and-disadvantages-of-defines-vs-constants) ).