# Comparing NSNumber value with defined int

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to store a constant int value to compare against in a particular scenario. My define looks like this:

```
#define kApiSuccessCode 0
```

And I have a method which compares a statuscode (`NSNumber`) with this to give a `BOOL` result:

```
- (BOOL)isSuccess {
    return [self.statusCode isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kApiSuccessCode]];
}
```

I have a synthesized `NSNumber` property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *statusCode;
```

The problem is I get a Execution was interrupted, reason: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when running this code - I can't work out why? Is this a bad way to compare int values? Thanks

**SOLVED:**

Turns out I was making the basic mistake of trying to `NSLog` a `BOOL` value i.e `NSLog(@"Does this work? %@", [response isSuccess])`. So the code itself works - but THANK YOU to everyone for your suggestions for making this more efficient!

Comment: Once you figure this out, I would suggest this instead:  `return [self.statusCode intValue] == kApiSuccessCode;

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why the crash is occurring, but to answer your other question, yes, this is not a great way to compare int values.

There are valid reasons to store values in `NSNumber` instances, but in most cases it is overkill. If you do, in fact, have an `NSNumber` instance, just use `intValue` to get it's integer value and compare it to a primitive instead of creating a whole new instance.

If you look at Foundation classes, you'll see most of the time, they rely on `NSInteger` primitive types instead of `NSNumber` instances. For example, the `NSURLResponse` class uses an `NSInteger` to return the HTTP status code.

Answer (score 2):

I would enable Zombies as instructed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917557/937822).

It will then tell you if you are sending the message to a deallocated instance of the variable.

Once you figure this out, I would then suggest this instead:

```
- (BOOL)isSuccess {
    return [self.statusCode intValue] == kApiSuccessCode; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Advantage and disadvantages of #define vs. constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944041/advantage-and-disadvantages-of-defines-vs-constants)

`As mentioned by others, #define doesn't have a type associated with it`

=> kApiSuccessCode is not an integer, the pre-compiler just replace it with `0` before you program is compiled.

Comment: Yes your are right that kApiSuccessCode will be replaced by 0 but in above context it is an integer.