# Should I avoid using #define in C++? Why, and what alternatives can I use?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

For some kinds of programs I need to use a constant high value to indicate some properties of some variables. I mean let `color[i] = 1000000;` if the `i` node in a tree is unexplored. But I   quite often miswrite the number of 0s at the end, so I just wondered whether is it better to do it this way:

```
#define UNEXPLORED 1000000;
color[i] = UNEXPLORED;
```

I remember that somewhere I have read that it's much better to avoid using #define. Is it right? How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: Go through this thread . Best answer from there - `#define's` don't respect scope - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944041/advantage-and-disadvantages-of-defines-vs-constants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple constants, you can use either `const` or the new [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

```
constexpr unsigned int UNEXPLORED = 1000000;
```

In a case like this, it's no difference between using `const` and `constexpr`. However, "variables" marked `constexpr` are evaluated at compile-time and not at run-time, and may be used in places that otherwise only accepts literals.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using `auto` here?  The main use I see of `auto` is to avoid repeating type names, or spelling out complex, nested types.  This is neither, and spelling out explicitly the type here improves clarity.  (Similarly, why `constexpr`, rather than the traditional `const`?)

Comment: @JamesKanze - using `auto` here will produce an integral type that's large enough to hold the actual value. `unsigned int` isn't necessarily large enough to hold `1000000`, a problem that the macro doesn't have.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's an interesting aspect, which I hadn't thought of.  Depending on the context, it might be considered a disadvantage or an advantage.  (I assume that if `1000000` didn't fit in an `unsigned int`, the compiler will at least warn.)

Comment: @JamesKanze - I know I'm beating a dead horse, but in most contexts, the macro works fine, without needing baroque workarounds. `<g>`

Comment: @PeteBecker As you've pointed out, the macro does the same thing as `auto`.  (Almost: if an inline function does a `push_back` of it into a vector, the `#define` is the only solution which doesn't have undefined behavior.  Or the enum constant, but that's really only justified if either you have a lot of them, that you want to group, or you want to limit scope, say in a class.)  Using an explicit type ensures that the constant _has_ that type.  Which may be useful at times.

Answer (score 4):

For example use constants.

```
const unsigned int UNEXPLORED = 1000000;
```

or enums

```
enum { UNEXPLORED = 1000000 };
```

Comment: It's getting more monre confusing for me. :( I am trying to learn a specific part and then come thousands of others. :( What's the difference between ENUM and STRUCT? Which to use for what?

Comment: @gen For questions like this, I'd suggest you grab a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to guide your learning.

Comment: The first doesn't work on systems where `unsigned int` is too small to hold `1000000`. And creating an `enum` just to hold a single constant is icky. `<g>`

Answer (score 0):

In the use of constants the two answers above are correct, however `#define` is not limited to that use alone. Another example of the use of `#define` is macros.

**Macros**

Macros are preprocessor-utilised pieces of code, and they work exactly like other `#define` declarations in that regard. The preprocessor will literally swap out the occurrence of your defined symbol with the code of the macro. An example:

```
#define HELLO_MAC do{ std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }while(false)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     HELLO_MAC;
}
```

That will literally swap out the `HELLO_MAC` symbol with the code I declared. If it were a constant it would do the exact same thing. So you can think of `#define`s for constants as a particular kind of macro.

With macros you can also pass parameters, and it is especially useful I find for enforcing logging/exception policies over code.
For example

```
#define THROW_EXCEPT( ex_type, ex_msg ) /
    do{ throw ex_type( buildExString( (ex_msg), __LINE__, __FILE__ ) ); }while(false)

... 
// somewhere else
THROW_EXCEPT( std::runtime_error, "Unsupported operation in current state" );
```

That code allows me to ensure that everyone logs with the line of the file that threw the exception.

Templates are often a better choice instead of macros, but I cannot use template functions for this example because I need to use the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` functions from the place of the throw, not from the location of the template function.

Where should you not use macros? Anywhere you can use something else. Macros, like any `#define` are preprocessed, so the compiler does not see them at all. This means that there is never any symbols created for `HELLO_MAC` or `THROW_EXCEPT`, and so they cannot be seen in a debugger. They can also be confusing if you get compile errors, especially if they are long macros.