# C initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, compiler-errors, constants

I'm getting a "error: initializer element is not constant"
with this code:

```
typedef struct {
    const int x;
    const int y;
} my_struct;

const int a = 8;
const int b = 12;

my_struct test = { a, b };
```

Any idea of what's going on and how to fix it ?

Comment: Note that this wouldn't be a problem if you initialized it inside a function instead (from C99 onwards).

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, using a `const` modifier does not produce a compile-time constant value.

Then, as per the rules of initialization, `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration
>   shall be constant expressions or string literals.

you'll be needing a constant-expression (compile time constat).

You may use a `#define` MACRO instead to get the result you want. Something like (warning: Code not tested)

```
#include  <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    const int x;
    const int y;
} my_struct;

//const int a = 8;
//const int b = 12;

#define a 8                  //use preprocessor MACROs
#define b 12                 //use preprocessor MACROs

my_struct test = { a, b };

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: enlightenment, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Besides [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47309991/2932052) (which have their [downsides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944041/advantage-and-disadvantages-of-define-vs-constants?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1854616_1944041)), unnamed enumerations are often used for the purpose to just provide compile-time constants. This would change your code like this.

```
typedef struct {
    const int x;
    const int y;
} my_struct;

enum {
    a = 8,
    b = 12, 
};

my_struct test = { a, b };
```

... also expressions involving compile-time constants can be compile-time constants themselves ...

```
my_struct test1 = { a+1, b };
my_struct test2 = { a, 'H' };
```

Also the `sizeof` operator can produce compile-time constants:

```
my_struct test3 = { sizeof(my_struct), b };
```

Even if this example looks not very useful, [it compiles](https://ideone.com/yEt0yv).

For learning what exactly constant expressions are, see for example [Constant expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) - despite the URL (`cppreference.com`), this is the *C reference* part.