# Why and where should enum be used in C

Tags: c, enums

I am a bit confused by what for and where enum is good? What are the benefits of using enum against defining global variables (constants) or macros? For instance in this code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

enum bool {false, true};

int main()
{
    enum bool b = 100;
    printf("%d", b);
    return 0;
}
```

I can assign even any integer value to `b` and every thing works fine, so why not doing

```c
int false = 0, true = 1;
```

or

```c
#define false 0
#define true 1
```

in the global scope? Can some one explain where and why are enums useful and should be preferred to use?

Comment: If you use the `enum` type, the compiler understands all possible values for the value.

Comment: You can use the enum type when declaring variables and functions.

Comment: Can you explain more please? perhaps with an example?

Comment: It makes the intent self-documenting. If you just declare the variable to be `int`, there's no way to tell that it should only contain ` true/false` value.

Comment: @Barmar Means it is intended more for the readability of code rather than having effect on the program execution?

Comment: In many cases, an enumeration is almost the opposite of a constant. You define a constant (or a macro) when you want to give a name to an important value; you define an enumeration when you want a set of names and don't really care about the underlying values. (That's not _always_ the case, but it's a good starting point.)

Comment: Enumerations are good for representing small sets of values that aren't normally ordered, or where arithmetic operations aren't meaningful (an example I gave in another answer was `enum cartype { sedan, suv, hatchback, coupe };`).  One advantage of using enumeration constants over preprocessor macros is that the constant name is preserved in debuggers, where the macro is not (e.g., if you have an object `enum cartype car = sedan;` and you examine the value in the debugger, the debugger will show `sedan` instead of `0`).

Comment: Side-note: you should use C's `stdbool` instead of defining your own `true`/`false` values.

Answer (score 3):

There are many advantages to using [enum](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-enum-c/) over #define macros:

> [Advantage and disadvantages of #define vs. constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944041/advantage-and-disadvantages-of-define-vs-constants)
>
> The use of an enumeration constant (enum) has many advantages over
> using the traditional symbolic constant style of #define. These
> advantages include a lower maintenance requirement, improved program
> readability, and better debugging capability.

I would also encourage you to use [bool](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bool-in-c/) (and `<stdbool.h>`) instead of an enum for true/false.

Comment: Thanks for the links, however I am more interested in enums rather than booleans here!

Comment: Please read the links I cited (you can easily find many others!) on "enum".  To explicitly answer your question "Q: when should I use them?"  A: Just about whenever possible :)  One big exception: generally, you should *NOT* use enums in preference to "bool" for true/false values (as in your example).  Nor should you use "int true=1" or equivalent.  I hope that helps :)