# Why won't this particular C code compile?

Tags: c

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int const NAMESIZE = 40;
int const ADDRSIZE = 80;
typedef char NameType[NAMESIZE];
typedef char AddrType[ADDRSIZE];

typedef struct
{
    NameType name;
    AddrType address;
    double salary;
    unsigned int id;
} EmpRecType;

int main(int * argc, char * argv[])
{
    EmpRecType employee;
    return 0;
}
```

If I use `#define` instead of `const` it compiles.

This is the error:

> employee.c:5:14: error: variably modified 'NameType' at file scope 
> employee.c:6:14: error: variably modified 'AddrType' at file scope

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variably modified array at file scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712592/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const int` instead of `int const`?

Comment: `int const` is valid in C++ - not sure if they also made the same thing valid in C.

Comment: maybe so .. I switched them around and it still doesn't compile.. I'm using gcc 4.5.3

Comment: @Benoit Garret: The `const` keyword is left associative, i.e. it acts upon what's left to it. The exception is if `const` is the first token in a statement, but then and only then. This semantics is the same in C and C++.

Comment: It isn't a good duplicate target (it is for Objective-C). The one for C is *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the differences between C and C++ is that in C++ a `const int` object is a *constant*, i.e. it can be used to form *constant expressions*. In C, on the other hand, a `const int` object is not a constant at all (it's more like "unchangeable *variable*").

Meanwhile, array size for file scope arrays in C is required to be a *constant expression*, which is why your `const int` object does not work in that role. (The above means, BTW, that your code will compile perfectly fine as C++, but won't compile as C.)

In C language to define named constants you have to use either `#define` or enums. In your specific case it could be done as follows

```
#define NAMESIZE 40
#define ADDRSIZE 80
```

P.S. If you replace your file-scope arrays with local arrays, your C code will compile as is, i.e. with `const int` objects as array sizes, because modern C (ANSI C99) supports variable-length arrays (VLA) in local scope. (And your arrays will be VLA in that case). In older versions of C (like ANSI C89/90) the code will not compile even with local arrays.

Answer (score 7):

Those const declarations, in C, just define some read only memory, they are not true constants. They can't be evaluated until runtime which is too late for the array declarations.