# Initializing global array and const modifier

Tags: c++

Having this simple C++ code:

```
// there MUST be the *const* keyword!
const int g_size = 8;
char g_arr[g_size] = {0};

int main(){
    // there MUST'T be the *const* keyword
    int l_size  = 8;
    char l_arr[l_size] = {0};
    ...
}
```

Can someone please explain me why does the **global** array *g_arr* CAN'T be initialized using non *const* variable (removing the modifier yields an error "array bound is not an integer constant...") but local array *l_arr* CAN?

Comment: No, `l_arr` can't be initialized like that either. It's a gcc extension that allows it, but it's not standard.

Comment: @cigien Even if gcc allows it, i would argue that you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @Amachi Absolutely, I feel that "it's not standard" implies that one shouldn't do that :)

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @cigien ahh okay, good :)

Comment: So gcc extension **allows** defining the local arrays with non-constant variables but **disallows** (as the standard says) defining the global arrays with non-constant variables?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075194/variable-length-arrays-vla-in-c-and-c