# Declaring an "int" type variable and taking input for same variable then declaring a array for that, highlights an error

Tags: c, c-strings

Below is the code that works properly fine and shows the correct output.

But it highlights an error in the line `char name[n]`, But why?

1. I have already declared `n` and taken its input.

Then, I declare the array `name[n]` which is highlighting `n` under the `char name[n]`.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int n;
    printf("\n Enter the value of n - ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    char name[n];   // <--------
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        name[i] = getch();
        printf("*");
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",name[i]);
    }

    getch();
   }
```

Comment: Read about VLA in C:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075194/variable-length-arrays-vla-in-c-and-c

Comment: `*char name[n];*` Is the two `*` part of your code ??

Comment: "But it highlights an error..." Is that your editor that highlights something?

Comment: Your editor probably highlights which line because in previous versions of C it was not possible to declare a variable after using a statement/function nor does it initialize array sizes with non-constant values. Maybe in the ide configuration you can change the version of C you are using.

Comment: Most likely you are using a Microsoft C++ compiler that does not support variable length arrays or another compiler in strict C++ mode. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: certainly but probably the ide does not know and highlights (.. and then you stop making me feel old :^D)

Comment: @dmaxime: We get people using some old software on Stack Overflow, but it is not **probable** that OP is using an IDE so old that it complains about declarations after statements, which has been allowed in C since the 1999 standard (and before that in compilers). [My prior comment was wrong about ANSI C, from 1990.]

Comment: ANSI C does not support dynamic length arrays.

Comment: @4386427 yes my editor highlights the error. I am using visual studio code.

Comment: @4386427 the "*" is not the part of the code, that I made to highlight the particular line in the source code.