# Output on codeforces and vs code is different for same code and input

Tags: c++

Input is same for both platforms

```
8 5
10 9 8 7 7 7 5 5
```

[Codeforces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWGKl.png)

[VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mExk6.png)

what is this happening?
is there something wrong in my code?

Code--->

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    int a[n];
    int k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int p=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
        if(a[i]>0){
            if(a[i]>=a[k-1]){
                p++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int n; int a[n];` -- This is wrong in multiple ways.  The first way is that this is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime value.  Also, even if there were valid syntax, what is the value of `n` when you started to use it? 
 Stop using online competition websites to learn C++, and use proper, peer-reviewed C++ books and materials.  A good C++ book would *never* show arrays being declared using a non-constant integer.  Why?  Because it isn't C++.

Comment: [Doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/385Evjhco).  All because of the invalid array syntax.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are accomplished this way:  `std::vector<int> a(n);`, given that `n` actually was set to a value.

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172416/uninitialized-variable-behaviour-in-c), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180417/what-happens-when-i-print-an-uninitialized-variable-in-c) and [Dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075194/variable-length-arrays-vla-in-c-and-c).

Answer (score 0):

what do you think this does

```
int n;
int a[n];
```

n is some random value, you then use that to size your array. You must read n first

Note that VLA (variable length arrays) are not standard c++. Use std::vector instead