# Compiler error "error: variably modified 'string' at file scope"

Tags: c

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int STRING_SIZE = 40;
typedef char string[STRING_SIZE];

char typeInput(string message);

int main()
{
    typeInput("Hi my name is Sean");
}

char typeInput(string message)
{
    printf(" %s", message);
}
```

Error:

> error: variably modified 'string' at file scope

I keep getting this error for some reason. Where did I go wrong?

Just in case, I'm using [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks).

Comment: I named the char variable "string"

Comment: Wait what do you mean (noob programmer)

Comment: `const int STRING_SIZE = 40;` --> `#define STRING_SIZE 40`. Also Change type of  return of `typeInput` to `void` from `char`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712592/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope

Comment: @melpomene: No, that is for [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C), not [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)* (see also [the linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/13645936)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

In C, `const` doesn't declare a constant, it declares a read-only variable. The compiler complains because `STRING_SIZE` is not a constant.

Workaround:

```
enum { STRING_SIZE = 40 };
// enum creates constants in C (but only integer ones)
```