# Why can array size parameters not be variables, when declared outside of functions?

Tags: c

Why is it not possible to declare an array outside of a function with variables as size parameters in C99?

For example, consider this code snippet.
It results in an `error: variably modified ‘matrix’ at file scope` compile error.

```
static int const height = 5;
static int const width = 5;
static int const matrix[height][width] = { ... };

int main(void){ ... }
```

I know that const in c doesn't mean constant. It means "read only", but I don't properly understand what implications this have.
So why can't arrays get their size from read-only memory?

I know this problem can be solved using [`#defines`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13645995/4755799) or [`enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1713799/4755799) so i am more interested in an explanation as to why this is the case.

Comment: Are you required to use C 1999? If you do not have a specific requirement to use C 1999, you should prefer the latest version of the standard, which is now the 2018 version.

Comment: Because this is how C is defined. The language has a burdensome old rule that an array size (at file scope) must be an _integer constant expression_, which in turn restricts what you can use as array size. It's to be regarded as a language bug. C++ has fixed the bug, C has not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, yes C99 is required for this project.

Comment: Consider a tighter meaning than `const` means "read only".

`const` means it is UB to attempt to change.  It could "work".  Given that, `static int const matrix[height][width]` does not represent a fixed size array with `static int const height = 5`. In order for `matrix[height][width]` to be a fixed size, `height` must be constant and `const` does not specify that.

Comment: The canonical may be *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C99 6.7.5.2/2 Array declarators:

> Only ordinary identifiers (as defined in 6.2.3) with both block scope or function prototype scope and no linkage shall have a variably modified type. If an identifier is declared to be an object with static storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

Comment: I think the point here is not to use the array as a VLA, but rather why a `const` qualified variable can't be used as array size.