# Memory optimization while using const vs #define in C++. Is it dependent on types?

Tags: c++

While reading merits and demerits of using a #define macro vs an equivalent const type I encountered contradictory statements.

1. Preprocessor replaces instance of macro with its values and as many object copies are created as many instances whereas using a const leads to only one object copy.
2. Compilers do not set aside storage for constant integral types. Also macros do not do any unnecessary memory allocation.

Example quoted for statement 1

```
#define PI 3.14

const float pi = 3.14;
```

Example quoted for statement 2

```
#define COUNT 10

const int count = 10;
```

Is optimization behavior dependent on types used under context as it looks from quoted examples? Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442328/what-is-the-difference-betweem-define-and-const

Comment: Your first example (PI) is not an *integral* type.

Comment: Just don't bother. Just **don't.** This is **not** a good place for "optimization". This is unnecessary bit-whacking, not optimization.

Comment: Both sentences are meaningless. Modern compilers just do the right thing, always.