# Should you use extern "C" in a file that only has defines?

Tags: c++, c, extern-c

Is it pointless to have:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
#endif

// code...

#ifdef __cplusplus
  }
#endif
```

Where "code..." is just a bunch of defines and typedefs (no includes, etc.)?

Comment: It is less valuable now as C and C++ continue to diverge but is useful, at low cost, for inter-language portability,

Answer (score 2):

In principle, in your particular case (no variable or function declaration), the `extern "C"` is pointless.

In practice, it makes the code more readable (showing the intent of defining a C++ friendly interface) and less brittle. Some developer (perhaps you) might (in a few months) add other declarations inside it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I don't work as a team, I'm a grade 9 school student who does this as a hobby. Even though I would love to work in a team; no-one else in my school programs.

Comment: But even if you are alone, you need to write some code that you'll be able to understand in a few months

Comment: Good point, I've decided to fully comment my code and add the extern "C" to every header file. I'm going to put a repo on github too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you intend the header to be used.

If the types and values are valid and have the same meaning in both C and C++, and you intend to use them from some compilation units compiled as C and others compiled as C++, then you need to use `extern "C"` when compiling as C++.   Otherwise, your C++ code and C code cannot interoperate.

If the header file is included by compilation units will only ever be built as C, as C++, but never as both, then you don't need `extern "C"`.    And you can use features specific to your chosen language.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've decided to exclude the extern "C". This is simply just because the only typedef is unsigned char, and the defines are just hexa-decimal integer values.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you may wish to consider using `const`s, rather than `#define`s.   The advantages of `const`, assuming a reasonable quality compiler, tend to exceed the benefits of using macros.  For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442328/what-is-the-difference-between-define-and-const and linked duplicates.