# Defining the complex constant "i" in C++ (#define vs const)

Tags: c++, math, constants, c-preprocessor

I'm wondering what is the "best practice" to define the complex constant "i" in C++.

I know that the "`#define` vs `const` in C++" question has been asked multiple times, and that the general answer is that it's best to use `const.`

However, I'm thinking that it makes sense to use `#define` instead of `const` to define mathematical constants (such as "i" or "pi"), because we don't think of them as *variables*, but "absolute constants" (in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393776/difference-between-a-macro-and-a-const-in-c), one can read: "A constant defined with the const qualifier is best thought of as an *unmodifiable* ***variable***."). Also, I see that in the `math.h` library, constants are defined this way, e.g. `#define M_E         2.71828182845904523536028747135266250   /* e */`.

So I'm wondering, how do C++ programmers usually define the complex constant i?

Lastly, I have a small issue with my current code `#define I std::complex<double>(0.0, 1.0)`: precompilation causes a name clash with a Qt library that I use (as soon as I enable C++11 support).

Comment: In C++11 you could use `{0, 1}` in the right context...

Comment: Really, why? Do you have a link explaining this?

Comment: The last issue is exactly why it's best to avoid macros: they don't respect language-level concepts such as scope. They just vomit over any use of the name in any context.

Comment: @Seub: It's just the new brace-initialization syntax...

Comment: I see, thanks! I think I still want to define i, though.

Comment: No offense, I was just responding to _I think I still want to define i, though_. Perhaps you meant _define a symbolic name_ (instead of writing it out everywhere), when I thought you meant `#define`?

Comment: Indeed, alright then.

Comment: `M_E` is non-standard, but it's probably inherited from C implementations, where `const` declarations don't create compile-time constants.

Answer (score 2):

Best practise is to declare a static const instance, with either a distinctive name or in a namespace.

---

Your `#define` does *not* define a mathematical constant. It defines a macro which expands to `std::complex<double>(0.0, 1.0)`. Why are they different?

### 1. Scope

Every time the compiler finds a token called `I`, whether it could be a variable name or not, will be replaced. It doesn't matter if it's a type name, a template parameter, a variable or a function argument - it will be replaced. It doesn't matter if it's in a namespace either, since the preprocessor doesn't understand them. You've already seen this break Qt, which is precisely the reason macros are generally deprecated for declaring constants.

Where they *are* used, it's vital to make sure the name is unique - but there's no easy way to do this.

### 2. Semantics

If I declare a static constant variable (ie, one that doesn't vary despite the name), it's useable just like any instance of that type - and a smart optimizer can probably avoid loading the global. However, the macro declares a new anonymous temporary each time it is referenced. There will be at least some cases where the duplicate instances can't be elided.

Comment: I thought static is not needed in C++?

Comment: @Seub: `static` has different purposes depending on how it is used.  Inside a class, it allows one instance of the member.  When declared in the scope of a translation unit (free standing), it limits the visibility (access) to the item.

Comment: I mean, I thought `static const` is not needed, just `const` will do?

Comment: Yes, that'll be fine, I just added a useless `static` from habit.