# std::compare_exchange int with #define value

Tags: c++, compare-and-swap

- I want to use `std::compare_exchange_strong` for some `std::atomic<int>`
- For compilation reasons (`int &`) I am forced to introduce `int _OLD_VALUE = OLD_VALUE`.
- Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?
- Here is my example

```
#include <atomic>
#include <stdio.h>
#define OLD_VALUE 16
#define NEW_VALUE 744
#define OTHER_VALUE 80
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::atomic<int> i(OTHER_VALUE);
    int _OLD_VALUE = OLD_VALUE;
    bool    status = i.compare_exchange_strong(_OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE);
    // bool status = i.compare_exchange_strong( OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE);
    if (status) { printf("good\n"); }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the compilation error when I use the commented version:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:11:65: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::__atomic_base<int>::__int_type& {aka int&}’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
     bool status = i.compare_exchange_strong( OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE);
                                                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/atomic:41:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/atomic_base.h:496:7: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘bool std::__atomic_base<_IntTp>::compare_exchange_strong(std::__atomic_base<_IntTp>::__int_type&, std::__atomic_base<_IntTp>::__int_type, std::memory_order) [with _ITp = int; std::__atomic_base<_IntTp>::__int_type = int; std::memory_order = std::memory_order]’
       compare_exchange_strong(__int_type& __i1, __int_type __i2,
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Ref. [Why is it allowed to pass R-Values by const reference but not by normal reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102728/why-is-it-allowed-to-pass-r-values-by-const-reference-but-not-by-normal-referenc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The reason being is that the previous value of the variable is exchanged so the `expected` value is overwritten if the compare mismatches.

To see what's going on under the hood, look at the GCC built-ins:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html

You will note there is a `__atomic_exchange_n` in the builtins for GCC (Linux) but that simply provides an exchange as opposed to a compare-and-swap.  The Windows equivalent is `InterlockedExchange` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedexchange

For the sake of readability I would avoid using capitals in variable names and avoid leading underscores:

```
int oldValue = OLD_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (and I suppose the only way) to achieve this is to just write simple wrapper:

```
bool cas_strong(std::atomic<int>& a, int cmp, int exc) {
  return a.compare_exchange_strong(cmp, exc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`compare_exchange_strong` expects an `int&` to store the current value found in `i`. Here, you provide indirectly `16` (that is what your macro `OLD_VALUE` is replaced with at pre-processing), which is an integer compile-time constant, a.k.a. `constexpr int&`. This is not compatible with `int&`.

To provide an `int&`, you should better keep an `int` near your call of `compare_exchange_strong`:

```
std::atomic<int> i(OTHER_VALUE);
int old_value = OLD_VALUE;
bool status = i.compare_exchange_strong(old_value, NEW_VALUE);
if (status) { printf("good\n"); }
return 0;
```

Also, more generally, it is clearly more powerful if you used static constants instead of macros here.
More on this in this other question: [What is the difference between a macro and a const in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393776/what-is-the-difference-between-a-macro-and-a-const-in-c)

Comment: 16 is an `int` prvalue, and it needs an `int` glvalue.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use macros to define the values:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <stdio.h>
int OLD_VALUE 16
int NEW_VALUE 744
int OTHER_VALUE 80
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::atomic<int> i(OTHER_VALUE);
    bool status = i.compare_exchange_strong( OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE);
    if (status) { printf("good\n"); }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really bad idea - `compare_exchange_strong` call will overwrite `OLD_VALUE`

Comment: These are not constants. `OLD_VALUE` is modified by `compare_exchange_strong`.

Comment: @dewaffled I don't understand can you elaborate? I wrongly wrote "constants" but of course there are no constants here

Comment: The idea is that `OLD_VALUE` should be constant but then copied to some non-`const` variable that itself gets compare/exchanged. You make `OLD_VALUE` non-constant and change it, breaking subsequent calls.

Comment: @idclev463035818 `compare_exchange_strong` stores `OTHER_VALUE` value to `OLD_VALUE` argument so it cannot be reliably reused anywhere else.

Comment: @dewaffled I dont see this in the question. I thought it is only about passing an integer literal where a non-const ref is required