# #define MY_INT VS const int MY_INT

Tags: c++, constants, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“static const” vs “#define” in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c)

When I do this :

```
#define WEEKDAYS 7
```

and that :

```
const int WEEKDAYS = 7;
```

Any difference between them ? seems that both do the same thing - sets a constant value for future usage within the code .

Comment: You've tagged this as both C and C++. The answers are somewhat different for the different languages.

Comment: It'd be easier to say **NEVER** tag a question both C and C++.

Comment: @JeffMercado It'd be easier, but it'd be wrong. :) The easiest example is a question asking specifically about one of the differences between C and C++ (I recall a recent question asking why `sizeof('a')` differs from `sizeof(char)` in C, but not in C++)

Comment: @hvd: What that's a question about specific differences between the two languages. What I really meant was tagging with both tags on a question that's not specifically looking for a comparison of the languages. But whatever, it's still going to happen whether we like it or not.

Comment: Agreed. FWIW, this is now closed as a duplicate of the question for C, but as ron has removed the C tag (thanks), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define (linked in the other question) may be useful to mention here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#define WEEKDAYS 7

void f() {
    int WEEKDAYS = 3; // error
}

const int WEEKDAYS_CONST = 7;

void g() {
    int WEEKDAYS_CONST = 3; // okay: local scope for WEEKDAYS_CONST
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#define WEEKDAYS 7
```

Replaces all occurrence of the word `WEEKDAYS` in your source file with the digit 7.

```
const int WEEKDAYS = 7;
```

Defines an actual constant represented by 7 that you can access in your code.