# How do I access #define Variable from one structure in a C file?

Tags: c, structure, c-preprocessor

```
#define MAX 7
#define BUFFER 16
#define MODULO 8

typedef struct {
int x;
} BLAH;
```

if I have:

```
  checkWindow(BLAH *b) {  
  int mod;   
  mod = b.MODULO; 
  }
```

Specifically can I access MODULO from the BLAH structure?

Comment: Huh, what? Q makes little to no sense.

Comment: If you really want to introduce a global c variable, I would prefer a static const over a define.  With a define, you run the risk of the compiler seeing something like `MAXIMUM` and changing it to `7IMUM`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1637332/18192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the meaning of preprocessor definitions. `#define`-d items only look like variables, but they are not variables in the classical sense of the word: they are *text substitutions*. They are interpreted by the [*preprocessor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), before the compiler gets to see the text of your program. By the time the preprocessor is done, the text of the program has no references to `MAX`, `BUFFER`, or `MODULO`: their occurrences are substituted with `7`, `16`, and `8`. That is why you cannot access `#define`-d variables: there are no variables to access.

Answer (score 0):

All #defines will be replaced in plain text by the "values" they define, before compilation. They are not variables, just short-hand syntax to make writing programs easy. None of your #def stuff actually reaches the compiler, its resolved in preprocessor.

Now, if you simply replace MODULO in your example by 8, does the resulting code make sense to you?
If it does make sense, please take a Computer Programming 101 course.