# Why using define or static const?

Tags: c++

What is preferable to use between:

```
#define PI 3.14159265
```

and

```
static const float PI=3.14159265
```

I know that define is used at compilation time and static const is used at execution time. Is just that I don't know which one to use and why?

Comment: for C++11 use constexpr.

Comment: Related to [“static const” vs “#define” in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c) and [static const vs #define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define).

Comment: For C++14 use a [template variable](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3651.pdf).