# Classes in other header files?

Tags: c++, class

I have a class in another .h and .cpp file from my main.cpp.

In main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "filestuff.h"
#include "stream.h" <-- right here

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    if(!args[1])
        return 0;

    u64 filesize = 0;
    get_file_size(args[1], &filesize);
    u8* fd = new u8[filesize];
    read_file(args[1], fd, filesize);

    Stream s = new Stream(fd, filesize, "rb", BigEndian );

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

In Stream.h

```
#include <iostream> //just in case?

#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_MSC_VER)
    typedef __int64 s64;
    typedef unsigned __int64 u64;
#else
    typedef long long int s64;
    typedef unsigned long long int u64;
#endif

typedef unsigned long int u32;
typedef signed long int s32;
typedef unsigned short int u16;
typedef signed short int s16;
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef signed char s8;

#define LittleEndian 0x1
#define BigEndian 0x2

class Stream
{
public:
    Stream(u8* buffer, u64 length, char* access, int IOType);
private:
    u8* buffer;
    u64 pos;
    u64 len;
};
```

In Stream.cpp

```
#include "stream.h"

Stream::Stream(u8* buffer, u64 length, char* access, int IOType)
{
    u8* buf = new u8[length];
    buffer = buf;
}
```

How can I use the following code to initialize my class like I want to do in `main` now?

```
Stream* s = new Stream(fd, filesize, "rb", BigEndian );
```

Comment: Do you have any error ? Or something ?

Comment: you mean Stream* s = new....

Comment: Or simply: `Stream s(fd, filesize, "rb", BigEndian);`

Comment: Yeah @alexbuisson Stream* doesn't work either. I just removed to see if it would fix

Comment: "How can I use the following code" - you can't. It's broken. So is `Stream::Stream`, since repointing the `buffer` argument won't affect the caller, and you're not freeing memory anywhere. You should be asking what you *should* be doing, not "how do I make the answer I'm using be the right answer".

Comment: Post any error messages you're seeing and, if possible, how the compiler is invoked. I suspect you're not compiling Stream.cpp or not linking main.o with Stream.o.

Comment: @user2357112 can you help? i've only done basic file IO in C++ and math and w/e

Comment: Also please use [<cstdint>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo in your code

Comment: @Jakes625 You don't need to correct the code in your question - that will make the answers obsolete and will make it harder for future readers to understand if they face similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error here :

```
Stream *s = new Stream(fd, filesize, "rb", BigEndian );
//     ^
```

The operator `new` return a **pointer to the newly allocated storage space**. So `s` has to be a pointer to get it working.

And you should have a destructor. You are allocating dynamic memory with `new[]`, you should free it before leaving :

```
Stream::~Stream()
{
    if ( NULL != buffer )
    {
        delete [] buffer;
    }
}
```

And when you don't need `s` anymore :

```
delete s;
```

Last error :

```
#define LittleEndian = 0x1
//                   ^
```

Remove the `=`.

**And in C++, it is a better practice to use `static const` variable :**

```
static const int LittleEndian = 0x1;
```

Look at this : [static const vs #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define)

**EDIT :**
 For the constructor :

```
Stream::Stream(u64 iLength, char* iAccess, int iIOType):
    mBuffer( new u8[iLength] )
{
}

// With mBuffer member of the Stream class.
```

Comment: better yet I could probably do if(buffer){ buff = new u8[len]; buffer = buff; }

Comment: I suggest to rename the arguments in your constructor or you members in your class, it is a bit confusing... Look at the edit.

Comment: the `~` is the caractere for the destructor. It is the method who is called at the destruction of the object. You should read this : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Answer (score 6):

Real error is in `#define LittleEndian = 0x1`. Remove `=`.

Comment: ahh gets me everytime!

Comment: Real solution: use `static const int LittleEndian = 0x1;`

Answer (score 0):

There are two probable mistakes. If you want a *pointer* to an object, write

```
Stream *s = new Stream(fd, filesize, "rb", BigEndian );
```

And if you want an object itself and not a pointer, write

```
Stream s(fd, filesize, "rb", BigEndian );
```

Answer (score 0):

in your main if you use dynamic allocation 
you must replace

```
     Stream s = new Stream(fd, filesize, "rb", BigEndian );
```

by

```
      Stream* s = new Stream(fd, filesize, "rb", BigEndian );
```

so s become a pointer on a Stream object.
all call to function of the stream class should be done with : s-> or (*s).

and don't forget to remove your memory with

```
 delete s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of errors pointed out so far. Here's another: In your constructor, you set

```
buffer = buf
```

That doesn't actually assign to the `Stream`'s `buffer` member. That assigns to the constructor's `buffer` argument. You most likely want

```
this->buffer = buf
```

That said, I'm not really sure why you take a buffer as an argument, only to allocate a different one. Maybe it'll make sense when you finish your code.

Comment: no you're right, I noticed that after I posted it. It's 1:40 AM. I really should have attempted this during day time. :/