# C++ Preprocessor definitions

Tags: c++

could anyone define what is a STRAY DEFINITION? .the second questionis:
I'm reading "Teach yourself c++ in 21 days" in the book he said we should not define the term DEBUG. I want to know why?

Comment: You should probably read your book.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `DEBUG` as far as I know.  You want to stay away from identifiers that start with underscores, though.  They're reserved for use by the implementation in various ways, so you might step on something's toes doing that.

Comment: People often use `DEBUG` as a flag to indicate debug-mode; there may be preprocessor conditionals in other people's code that say "if `DEBUG` is defined, then spit out a lot of diagnostic information". So it's not something you'd want to turn on unintentionally.

Comment: but you didn't explained STRAY DEFINITION. would you?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `STRAY DEFINITION`. I don't recall ever hearing the term before.

Comment: Doesn't MSVC (Visual Studio) use `-DDEBUG` when building in debug mode?  Though that may not be a big problem if you want your debug code to be compiled into your program when it is compiled for debug.

Comment: When using C++, stay away from `#define`s as much as possible.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First part of the question:

A **stray definition** is a preprocessor definition that changes the behavior of some other code (or the actual code), which most likely won't be intentional. For example, you could write a header file and use the following line:

```
#define main is_awesome
```

This won't have any direct impact in your header file, possibly not even in your code, but someone else including this header file in a file containing the function `int main(int argc, char **argv)` will run into problems, because this **stray definition** will change that function's name into `int is_awesome(int argc, char **argv)` and suddenly there is no longer a `main` entry point for the application!

In a similar way the macro `DEBUG` can cause such problems. Typically, `DEBUG` should only be defined by the compiler itself, based on whether it's building debug code or not (based on your compiler you might have to set it yourself as well). If you're defining `DEBUG` somewhere on your own, you might trigger debug code even though you're actually creating a release build.

In general, such bugs or issues can be really hard to track down, especially if you don't know how to have a look at the preprocessed code (you can't see the problems/errors in your base code and most likely line numbers reported will be off as well).

---

How to avoid this? Three simple rules that will make your life and that of others a lot easier:

- Only use preprocessor definitions when you really have to (e.g. to control code inclusion at compile time).
- Always clean up (`#undef`) preprocessor definition you don't need outside your header file.
- If you have to use some global preprocessor definition, make it's name unique, e.g. by prepending your library or project name. E.g. rather than defining `DEBUG` you could use `MYLIB_DEBUG`.