# Preprocessor Macros for Constants - Bad Form?

Tags: c++

Recently, I've been assigned to a project (C++) at work where there is a significant amount of string matching/parsing in an XML-ish document (similar to XML, but not quite; it's bizarre)  As a result, in order to both increase readability and reduce copy/paste errors, I've placed several macros at the top of several of my source files.  For reference, the macros are different in each file.  For example:

```
#define CATAGEORY_PATH "properties/event/classifications/classification/@category"
#define CLASSIFICATION_PATH "properties/event/classifications/classification/@classification"
```

Is what I did considered bad form and/or is there a better way to do this?  At the moment, I like this method as it is clear throughout the code what I have done, but something about #define for a string bothers me.

From the experienced coders in the crowd, what are your thoughts?  Also, from the professional developers, what do you think?  I apologize if the distinction offends anyone, but, in my experience, there can be a significant difference between both populations.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1637367/620197

Comment: It could be OK.  It's hard to tell without seeing the usage in context.  It's definitely better than it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative for constants is `static const`.

```
static const char category_path[] = "properties/event/classifications/classification/@category" ;
```

This way there is at least a little bit of type information decorated with it.