# Difference between using define and variable

Tags: c++

If I have the code below:

```
#define POUND_PER_DOLLAR  73
int nPound = 4 * POUND_PER_DOLLAR;
```

AND

```
int POUND_PER_DOLLAR = 122;
int nPound = 4 * POUND_PER_DOLLAR;
```

Are there instances where usage of one is more suited than the other?

Comment: Generally `#define` is used for constants

Comment: A good compiler should evaluate the second and avoid useless stack usage, anyway the macro is **not** typesafe

Comment: This might be of interest: [static const vs #define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define)

Comment: What happens if the exchange rate changes for your customer?

Comment: Why is you code shouting so much? It's unseemly. [Stop the constant SHOUTING](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1923)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the address, you need a variable:

```
void foo(int *);

foo(&POUND_PER_DOLLAR);         // must be an lvalue
```

If you need a constant expression, a macro (or at least a constant) will work:

```
char array[POUND_PER_DOLLAR];   // must be a constant expression
```

However, the most appropriate construction is probably a constant:

```
const int kPoundPerDollar = 73;
int nPound = 4 * kPoundPerDollar;

void bar(const int *);
bar(&kPoundPerDollar);                 // works
char c[kPoundPerDollar];               // also works

template <const int * P> struct X {};
X<&kPoundPerDollar> x;                 // also works
```

Comment: I'd also add something about type safety

Answer (score 3):

Neither. The `#define` is not type-safe, the `int` is non-const. This is the constant you're looking for :

```
int const POUND_PER_DOLLAR = 122;
```

Comment: except it looks fugly in ALL_CAPS and there's no good reason for that. [Stop the constant SHOUTING](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1923).

Answer (score 2):

```
#define identifier replacement
```

> When the preprocessor encounters this directive, it replaces any
>   occurrence of identifier in the rest of the code by replacement. This
>   replacement can be an expression, a statement, a block or simply
>   anything. The preprocessor does not understand C++ proper, it simply
>   replaces any occurrence of identifier by replacement.

Disadvantages of using #define:
method,

1. the preprocessor does not understand any c++, it only replaces
   it, so you are taking your own risk
2. It makes it harder for debugging, if you are using a debugger and you want to check the
   values of your variables
3. You Have to be careful of redefinition of your macro