# Should I use static const int or #define?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class and it has an integer value that will be used by other classes as well as the original class. And it's a fairly simple value (e.g. the dimensions of a GUI application). In this case, should I define these values as `static const int VALUE = 123` or `#define VALUE 123` in my header file? Does one have any advantage over the other?

Comment: That depends, there are cases where `static const` values might turn out less efficient than a simple `#define`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define

Comment: you should also consider constexpr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using C++ you almost never need to use `#define`. (Only with include guards)

`#define` knows nothing about semantics of code. It simply replaces text `VALUE` with defined value.

`static const int` is much better choice then. It is recommended way to use constants.

Comment: Even for include guards, most compilers support `#pragma once`.