# Does const use more or less memory than #define typically?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, constants

I understand how each works, but I was curious if one or the other actually is more efficient memory-wise. #define seems to be used all the time in the embedded C world, but I am wondering if it is actually justified over a const most of the time.

If one is more efficient than the other, does anyone have some way to test and show this?

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: Depending on your compiler. Why don't you add a global `const` variable to your program, use it somewhere in your code, and then check the disassembly to see if the compiler refers to it as a variable or replaces it with a fixed value?

Comment: You obviously _don't_ understand how each works. Sorry.

Comment: Ok... I apologize for not backing up my knowledge of the #define before trying to ask this question, was just trying to keep it simple for now. Saw some points on both sides here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define/1637367#1637367. Thought I would try to flesh out a better answer...

Comment: @radix07: The highest-rated comment on that answer dispels the myth that writing `#define` allows you to magically avoid using any memory.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding

Comment: If there is any difference in memory usage, it's going to be negligible.  If you really want to optimize your program, either in terms of its memory footprint or its speed, then you're barking up a very small tree here.  Write a program that works, then use run-time analysis tools to find where the bottlenecks are and optimize them.  In an embedded system, it's not uncommon to rewrite highly critical functions in assembly code, bypassing the C compiler altogether.

Comment: a const only uses memory once, in readonly memory,  and it is accessed via code.  A #define has its' text inserted at every point where the #define name is used.  If the #define value can be incorporated as part of a single machine instruction, then irregardless of how many times it is referenced, it will add less total ram usage that the const, because the const needs code to gen a pointer to it and code to actually retrieve it.  However, if the #define cannot be incorporated in a single instruction, then the const can easily take less total ram.  So the answer is: "it depends"

Comment: @user3629249  The "a const only uses memory once ..." comment would make an fine answer.

Comment: Traditionally, embedded device manufacturers supplied their own compiler and it was dreadful at optimizing, so `#define` was preferred in order to save memory.  Of course, a `const` variable is not a constant expression so in some cases you do not even have that option.

Answer (score 6):

Let's put `#define` aside, because it doesn't really exist in your program. The preprocessor takes your macros and expands them before the compiler can even spot that they were ever there.

The following source:

```
#define X 42
printf("%d", X);
```

is *actually* the following program:

```
printf("%d", 42);
```

So what you're asking is whether that takes more or less memory than:

```
const int x = 42;
printf("%d", x);
```

And this is a question we can't fully answer in general.

On the one hand, the value `42` needs to live in your program *somewhere*, otherwise the computer executing it won't know what to do.

On the other hand, it can either live hardcoded in your program, having been optimised out, or it can be installed into memory at runtime them pulled out again.

Either way, it takes 32 bits (it may not be 32) and it doesn't really matter how you introduced it into your program.

Any further analysis depends on *precisely* what you are doing with the value.

Comment: @radix07: I'm not convinced you've understood my answer, unfortunately. Why do you think "there has to be a general idea"?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on whether you are taking the address of the constant or not.  If you do *not* take the address of the constant, then the compiler has no problem folding it into other computations and emitting it inline (as an immediate or literal), just like the `#define`d version.  However, if you write:

```
const int c = 42;
const int *pc = &c;
```

then a copy of `c` must live in the global `.rodata` section in order to have its address taken, adding `sizeof(int)` bytes of Flash space atop any copies the compiler decided to inline; however, the compiler might be able to fetch that constant from memory more cheaply than it can incorporate it as an inline literal, depending on its value and what CPU you're compiling for.

Try compiling some code each way and looking at the resulting assembler listings...