# Is it reasonable to use enums instead of #defines for compile-time constants in C?

Tags: c, enums, constants, c-preprocessor

I'm coming back to some C development after working in C++ for a while. I've gotten it into my head that macros should be avoided when not necessary in favor of making the compiler do more work for you at compile-time. So, for constant values, in C++ I would use static const variables, or C++11 enum classes for the nice scoping. In C, static constants are not really compile-time constants, and enums may (? or may not?) behave slightly differently.

So, is it reasonable to prefer using enums for constants rather than #defines?

For reference, here's an [excellent list of pros and cons of enums, #defines and static consts in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835772/1593077).

Comment: As you said, there are profound differences between C and C++ regarding this topic. So there might not be a single answer that is valid for both languages.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I believe the question asks how to do this in C only (see title). The C++ part is just there for reference.

Comment: The tag should be removed, then.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: Ok, removed it for clarity.

Comment: " I've gotten it into my head that macros should be avoided when not necessary in favor of making the compiler do more work for you at compile-time"  Macros are evaluated at compile-time, so this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin I thought macros were evaluated by the preprocessor, not the compiler?

Comment: @daiscog It is part of the compiler and executes at compile-time...

Comment: @Lundin Agreed; I was just being technically pedantic.

Comment: @Lundin: I was thinking more about SFINAE-type things, and the possibility of having the compiler run my constexpr functions, type checking, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The advantage of using `enum { FOO=34 };` over `#define FOO 34` is that macros are preprocessed, so in principle the compiler don't really see them (in practice, the compiler *does* see them; recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) has a sophisticated infrastructure to give from what macro expansion some internal abstract syntax tree is coming).

In particular, the debugger is much more likely to know about `FOO` from `enum { FOO=34 };` than from `#define FOO 34` (but again, this is not always true in practice; sometimes, the debugger is clever enough to be able to expand macros...).

Because of that, I prefer  `enum { FOO=34 };` over `#define FOO 34`

And there is also a typing advantage. I could get more warnings from the compiler using `enum color_en { WHITE, BLACK }; enum color_en color;` than using `bool isblack;`

BTW, `static const int FOO=37;` is usually known by the debugger but the compiler might optimize it (so that no memory location is used for it; it might be just an immediate operand inside some instruction in the [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)).

Comment: And of course, the debugger is even more likely to know about `const` so that's usually the best option, if applicable.

Answer (score 7):

I would stick to using the features for their purpose.

A symbolic parameter, taking a discrete value among a set of alternatives, should be represented as an enum member.

A numerical parameter, such as array size or numerical tolerance, should be represented as a const variable. Unfortunately, C has no proper construct to declare a compile-time constant (like Pascal had), and I would tend to say that a defined symbol is equally acceptable. I now even unorthodoxically opt for defined symbols using the same casing scheme as other identifiers.

The enumerations with explicitly assigned values, such as binary masks, are even more interesting. At the risk of looking picky, I would consider to use declared constants, like

```
#define IdleMask 1
#define WaitingMask 2
#define BusyMask (IdleMask | WaitingMask)
enum Modes { Idle= IdleMask, Waiting= WaitingMask, Busy= BusyMask };
```

This said, I wouldn't care so much about easing the compiler's task when you see how easily they handle the monstrous pieces of code that they receive daily.

Comment: `BusyMask` is accident waiting to happen. Always surround non-trivial preprocessor constants with parenthesis.

Comment: Also, I would use `IdleMask 0x1 << 0` and `WaitingMask 0x1 << 1` (or `0x01` and `0x02` at least) to emphasize the bitwise reading of these.

Comment: @user694733: no the constant `BusyMask` is not intended to be used anywhere else; only `Busy` can be.

Comment: I think it's good practice to `#undef` temporary macros like that after use. Especially if that is going in a header. However that'll just even further bloat this verbose initialization, so somehow I don't see this catching on...

Answer (score 7):

I've been working in embedded systems for over a dozen years and use C primarily. My comments are specific to this field. There are three ways to create constants that have specific implications for these types of applications.

1) #define: macros are resolved by the C preprocessor before the code is presented to the C compiler. When you look at headers files provided by processor vendors, they typically have thousands of macros defining access to the processor registers. You invoke a subset of them in your code and they become memory accesses in your C source code. The rest disappear and are not presented to the C compiler.

Values defined as macros become literals in C. As such, they do not result in any data storage. There is no data memory location associated with the definition.

Macros can be used in conditional compilation. If you want to strip out code based on feature configuration then you have to use macro definitions. For example:

```
#if HEARTBEAT_TIMER_MS > 0
    StartHeartBeatTimer(HEARTBEAT_TIMER_MS);
#endif
```

2) Enumerations: Like macro definitions, enumerations do not result in data storage. They become literals. Unlike macro definitions, they are not stripped by the preprocessor. They are C language constructs and will appear in preprocessed source code. They cannot be used to strip code via conditional compilation. They cannot be tested for existence at compile time or runtime. Values can only be involved in runtime conditionals as literals.

Unreferenced enumerations won't exist at all in compiled code. On the other hand, compilers may provide warnings if enumerated values are not handled in a switch statement. If the purpose of the constant is to produce a value that must be handled logically then only an enumeration can provide the degree of safety that comes with the use of switch statements.

Enumerations also have an auto-increment feature, so if the purpose of the constant is to be used as an constant index into an array then I would always go with an enumeration to avoid unused slots. In fact, the enumeration itself can produce a constant representing a number of items that can be used in an array declaration.

Since enumerations are C language constructs, they are definitely evaluated at compiler time. For example:

```
#define CONFIG_BIT_POS 0
#define CONFIG_BIT_MASK (1 << CONFIG_BIT_POS)
```

CONFIG_BIT_MASK is a text substitute for (1 << CONFIG_BIT_POS). When (1 << CONFIG_BIT_POS) is presented to the C compiler, it may or may not produce the literal 1.

```
enum {
    CONFIG_BIT_POS = 0,
    CONFIG_BIT_MASK = (1 << CONFIG_BIT_POS)
};
```

In this case CONFIG_BIT_MASK is evaluated and becomes the literal value 1.

Finally, I would add that macro definitions can be combined to produce other code symbols, but cannot be used to create other macro definitions. That means that if the constant name must be derived then it can only be an enumeration created by a combination of macro symbols or macro expansion, such as with list macros (X macros).

3) const: This is a C language construct that makes a data value read only. In embedded applications this has an important role when applied to static or global data: it moves the data from RAM into ROM (typically, flash). (It does not have this effect on locals or auto variables because they are created on the stack or in registers at runtime.) C compilers can optimize it away, but certainly this can be prevented, so aside from this caveat, const data actually takes up storage in read only memory at runtime. That means that it has type, which defines that storage at a known location. It can be the argument of sizeof(). It can be read at runtime by an external application or a debugger.

These comments are targeted at embedded applications. Obviously, with a desktop application, everything is in RAM and much of this doesn't really apply. In that context, const makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

> is it reasonable to prefer using enums for constants rather than #define's ?

If you like. Enums behave like integers.

But I would still prefer constants, instead of both enums and macros. Constants provide type safety, and they can be of any type. Enums can be only integers, and macros do not respect type safety.

For example:

```
const int MY_CONSTANT = 7;
```

instead of

```
#define MY_CONSTANT 7
```

or

```
enum
{
  MY_CONSTANT = 7
};
```

---

BTW, my answer was related to C++. I am not sure if it applies to C.

Comment: Could you please provide some rationale Why do you prefer constants. This might not be immediately obvious.

Comment: In C some constructs require constants (labels of switch, static arrays, etc.) and const-qualified variables are not considered constants. So your answer applies only to C++.

Answer (score 3):

A `const int MY_CONSTANT = 7;` will take up storage; an enum or `#define` does not.

With a `#define` you can use any (integer) value, for example `#define IO_PORT 0xb3`

With an enum you let the compiler assign the numbers, which can be a lot easier if the values don't matter that much:

```
enum {
   MENU_CHOICE_START = 1,
   MENU_CHOICE_NEXT,
   ...
};
```

Comment: Everything takes up "storage", a program cannot allocate numbers in thin air. The difference is that defines or enums get merged in together with the code, increasing the size of the `.text` segment instead of increasing the `.rodata` segment. `const` is always to prefer if it is an option, because you can localize the scope of `const` variables and also view them in a debugger.

Comment: The compiler might optimize so that  `const int MY_CONSTANT=7;` has no memory location at all...

Comment: @Lundin, a ` const` takes up a memory location and requires a fetch instruction. A `#define` and enum value is placed in the instruction as an operand. The code size will be smaller as the additional fetch requries a 32 bit address (operand).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: the constant value will appear as an operand in the assembled code anyway. I agree that intermediate constants (just used to define other constants), could be fully optimized away.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie: That's a rather implementation-specific detail. These days when all the world seems to run on ARM non-trivial constants, or ones not known at compile-time, would tend to be placed as data in the literal pool. In any event the major benefit of enums over constant "variables" in C and `#define`  lies in being able to use then in compile-time expressions, such as array sizes.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie My point is: its incorrect to say that enum or define are not stored anywhere. Also you don't really know where a const end up, it depends a lot on the specific system and the level of optimization.

Comment: @Lundin You can also localize the scope of enum and use it in debugger.

Comment: @martinkunev Enumeration variables: yes. Enumeration constants: no.

Comment: @Lundin - I don't understand what you mean. If you put enum in a function, the constants it defines are only visible within the function.

Comment: @martinkunev I meant that you cannot view enumeration constants in a debugger. There are however some good debuggers that can display the values of an enum variable as textual enum constants, rather than plain integer values.

Comment: @Lundin I have absolutely no problem with any kind of enum constants in gdb - I can display their names and their values. Maybe some debuggers have problems with that though.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, in C++ there isn't any real good reason to use `#define` for compile-time constants. On the other hand, there are good reasons to use `enum`s or `enum class`es instead. First and most important—they are much more readable during debugging.

In C, you may want to explicitly choose underlying type, which is impossible with `enum`s. That might be a reason to use `define`s or `const`s. But enums should be strongly preferred.

Runtime overhead is not a problem—in modern compilers there won't be any difference in generated machine code (as long as `sizeof(the_enum)=sizeof(the_type_used_by_define_based_values)`).

Answer (score 1):

The TL;DR answer is that it doesn't often matter at all if you use `#define` or `enum`.

There are however some subtle differences.

The main problem with enums is that you can't change the type. If you use *enumeration constants* such as `enum { FALSE, TRUE };`, then those constants will always be of type `int`.

This might be problematic if you need unsigned constants, or constants of a different size than `sizeof(int)`. Signed integers may cause subtle bugs if you need to do bitwise operations, because mixing those with negative numbers doesn't make any sense in 99% of the cases.

With macros however, you can specify any type:

```
#define X 0                 // int type
#define X 0u                // unsigned int type
#define X 0ul               // unsigned long type
#define X ((uint8_t)0)      // uint8_t type
```

The downside is that you don't have to option to actually define a type with macros, which you could do with enums. enums give a slight bit more of type safety, but only if you typedef them: `typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} BOOL;`. C doesn't have much type safety at all, but good compilers or external static analysis tools can detect & warn for type issues when trying to convert to/from enum type by accident.

Another oddity with that though, is that "BOOL" is an enum variable. enum variables, unlike enum constants, have no guarantee of which integer type they correspond to. You just know that it will be some kind of integer type large enough to fit all values of the corresponding enumeration constants. This might be a very bad thing in case the size of the enum matters.

And of course, enums have the advantage that you can declare them at local scope, so you don't unnecessarily clutter down the global namespace when you don't need to.

Comment: Yes, the lax type control and lack of floating-point constants leads me largely to use enums for actual enumerations in C. Plus `#define` constants can be used in preprocessor expressions of course. Well, that and having been bitten by a particularly craptastic embedded compiler which always used 16-bit `int` for enums while silently truncating 32-bit constants.

Comment: @doynax It is indeed mainly in embedded systems where enums will cause most trouble.