# Is it necessary in #define to set the data type?

Tags: c

I have a question. When I make a `#define VAR 5` in c, is it necessary to define the type? like: `#define VAR (unit_8) 5`

I imagine, what is going on when I make this C code.

```
#define VAR 15000
void foo(uint_8);
void foo(uint_8 c) { c++; }
int main() {
  foo(VAR);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary, but good practice. That way you can guarantee the data type of the constant. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232075/is-it-reasonable-to-use-enums-instead-of-defines-for-compile-time-constants-in/33232548#33232548) for examples.

Answer (score 6):

You can't declare variables in `#define` statements. These are statements only for the preprocessor, and are only text replacements.

`VAR` in your case is NOT a variable, but a sort of constant that is processed by the preprocessor.

You can do

```
#define VAR 15000
uint_16 a = VAR;
```

But VAR itself is decidedly not a variable but only preprocessor text replacement. The compiler will, after the preprocessor has run, treat the above code as;

```
uint_16 a = 15000;
```

If you need a constant to use, you can do:

```
const int VAR = 15000;
```

Instead.

Comment: All constants have types though, even if they are not variables. It is good practice to be explicit about which type a certain constant has. There are cases when you cannot use `const` but have to use defines.

Comment: @Lundin in these cases you can use something like `#define var (int) 15000` but that doesnt change the fact that its just text replacement.

Answer (score 5):

**No**, it is not necessary. Macros do textual substitution. They have no idea about data types.

If want to define constants with a type, use `const T`:

```
const int var = 15000;
```

Otherwise, you could, just as you did, cast the constant in the macro:

```
#define VAR (unit_8) 15000
```

Note that integer literals may have different types (`15000` is **always** an `int`). You may adjust the type of a literal by appending [suffixes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) like `u`, `l`, etc.

```
15000lu = unsigned long
16000u = unsigned int
15000 = int
```

Comment: Could you write an example about your last note ?